# regarding the error message of float object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I uses the following line of code to define a multi-dimensional array to save a set of images represented as two-dimensional array as well.

```
 import numpy as np
 imgs = np.ndarray((100, 1, image_rows, image_cols), dtype=np.float32)
```

Here, `100` represents that there have 100 images in total.
However, running the program gives the following error message `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. What does it mean and how to solve it?

Comment: Are `image_rows` and `image_cols` ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that error if `image_rows` or `image_cols` are floating point values:

```
In [15]: imgs = np.ndarray((100, 1, 5.0, 10.0), dtype=np.float32)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c7783d157b42> in <module>()
----> 1 imgs = np.ndarray((100, 1, 5.0, 10.0), dtype=np.float32)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Convert the values to integers first:

```
imgs = np.ndarray((100, 1, int(image_rows), int(image_cols)), dtype=np.float32)
```